# Swiper JS slides per view and slides per column displaying incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I was trying to make a 2 rows of slides on bootstrap using swiper js using the [demo](https://swiperjs.com/demos/170-slides-per-column.html) given at the official page. However When I copied the code and ran on my browser it displayed like this[image]

The code is exactly the same as the demo page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../package/css/swiper.min.css">
     <style>

      .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
     }
     .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      height: calc((100% - 30px) / 2);

      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
     </div>

     <script src="../package/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

     <script>
      var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      slidesPerColumn: 2,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried changing the slides per view and slides per column but those were almost the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems that the setting `slidesPerColumn` does not work. Then I was checking which CSS comes from the swiper css with those Swiper Slide settings:

```
.swiper-container-multirow-column > .swiper-wrapper {
   flex-direction: column;
 }
```

It turned out that when i overwrite the CSS, it works:

```
.swiper-container-multirow-column > .swiper-wrapper {
  flex-direction: inherit;
}
```

Or instead, add the following setting:

```
slidesPerColumnFill: 'row'
```

I hope that helps (even if it is a late answer on this topic).

Comment: slidesPerColumnFill: 'row' dit the job thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If your using CDNs ->

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" >
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

replace it with ->

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/css/swiper.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

That will do the trick..Apparently many options are not working with the previous CDN

Answer (score 0):

Change container height

```
.swiper-container { height: 800px; }
```